# Send an email using Grails - beginner

Tags: grails

I uncommented the following in the BuildConfig.groovy file.

```
mail:1.0.4
```

Now i am trying to send confirmation emails.

I added the following in the config.groovy file.

```
grails {
   mail {
     host = "smtp.gmail.com"
     port = 465
     username = "youracount@gmail.com"
     password = "yourpassword"
     props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",                     
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]

   }
}
```

I also have a controller called `UserController.groovy`, it has a method called :

```
def sendEmail ()= {

 // how can i send the email

}
```

I am lost here what code should i include in order to successfully send this email?

Comment: There is no question in this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you would be doing in your controller file.

```
class UserController {

     def mailService // injecting the mail service bean in your controller.

     def sendEmail () {

        mailService.sendMail {
           to ....
           from ....
           ....
        }
     } 
}
```

Comment: I get this error `534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at 534 5.7.9 http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=185833 qo12sm41860326igb.21 - gsmtp`

Comment: @Illep and have you tried reading the page that the error message links to?  It looks like you have 2-step verification enabled on your gmail account.

Comment: Yes i do. But that page cann't be accessible.

Comment: @Illep If you have got to this point then your mail plugin is actually working. If you enable the verification process as pointed in the link then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need is on the [documentation](https://grails.org/plugins/mail):

Edit: @Illep, I updated the code using your last comment

Import the mailService and use the example below to send your email:

```
class UserController {

  def mailService

  def sendEmail() {

    mailService.sendMail {
       to "fred@g2one.com","ginger@g2one.com"
       from "john@g2one.com"
       cc "marge@g2one.com", "ed@g2one.com"
       bcc "joe@g2one.com"
       subject "Hello John"
       body 'this is some text'
    }
  }
}
```

For HTML email, it is a little bit different, and you are going to use groovy render.

Comment: I got this error `No such property: mailService for class: com.app.auth.UserController`

Comment: @Illep you have to make use of grails autowiring by convention.  when you call this code in a service you just have to add ``def mailService`` there.

Comment: You can drop the mailService part entirely and that should work the plugin takes care of that?